# Maxwell equation

Tags: ohms-law, electrostatic

$$
J = \sigma E - \frac{dD}{dt}
$$

I am having difficulties understanding this equation. I know that \$\small J = \sigma E\$ in the equation is a form of Ohm's law, but what is the other part?

Comment: Please edit your question with a citation for your source, as different sources use different symbols and terms.

Comment: [symbol definition](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/maxeq.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/maxeq.html), D appears to be electric displacement.
That means that in your simplified equation, over time, there is no change in the displacement field, so you can 0 that out. From what I can tell, the only way the displacement field changes over time is when point charges are changing locations. Although charges are moving in a circuit, when you're analyzing a section of it *at steady state DC*, there's no net change in the point charges at any given time because your power supply is replenishing the point charges.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field) gives more info on displacement fields.

Comment: Displacement field does change when, for example, a capacitor charges or discharges. In general, one cannot assume that the potential at a given point in a circuit is constant. However, in _steady state_, displacement field does not change over time, even though charges flow.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Thanks, I've edited the answer to clarify your point.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Displacement field is not necessarily constant in steady state if that steady state is not also pure DC.

Comment: @Hearth, I've heard some people refer to steady-state as DC, but you're right, more commonly, steady-state can be AC or DC. I'll correct that as well.